# Linux Server: Cannot upload files to any directory

Tags: linux, configuration, apache2, upload

I am working with an ubuntu server running apache2 but I can't upload files, but I can log in to ssh and 
    touch test.txt
When I log in to the server with filezilla and try to add a file to /var/www I get a 550: Permission denied error.

The server admin is away so asking is not a possibility but he did give me sudo privs before he left.  He set up the server in a hurry so is there something I can do that he may have forgotten that is basic or advanced?

Comment: You should ssh to your server and check permissions of `/var/www/` folder using command `ls -la /var/` and change permission of  `/var/www` directory to 777 using following command `sudo chmod 777 /var/www/` Once you're done with file upload change back permissions to earlier stage.

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue with others, which is 0, nothing permitted. I assume you logged in server with permitted user but ftp user is probably stuck with others permission.